# I have a React project with many modules. Is hosting it separately or together better?

Tags: reactjs, hosting, website-hosting

I have a React project with many modules. Is hosting it separately or together better? I have searched on the web for opinions but I don't get a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

why do we go separate host cost and any other things high when you go to a separate one. modules and project put it together. when you hosted in separate if one module was missing all projects was going down.put it together and host it will be easy and saving costs.

Answer (score 0):

To a certain point, it should be ok to host them in one piece. But when your application grows and you have loads of third-party libraries in use it might effect the performance of your app. So in this case I think it will be just fine to host them in one bundle.

https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html